# How to efficiently color quadrilaterals using bilinear gradients in PostScript

Tags: postscript

I am creating a PostScript drawing in which I have hundreds of quadrilaterals.  I want each of the quadrilaterals to be colored using a bilinear interpolation between four colors, each of which is associated with a vertex.

Currently, for each quadrilateral, I am using something along the lines of

```
newpath
<<
/BBox [294      353.6387      627.0481      644.4492
/Domain [294      353.6387      627.0481      644.4492
/ShadingType 6
/ColorSpace [/DeviceRGB]
/DataSource
[
0
   322.00000000    639.52198166
   308.00000000    633.28505452
   308.00000000    633.28505452
   294.00000000    627.04812738
   309.50334395    629.25461291
   309.50334395    629.25461291
   325.00668790    631.46109845
   339.32269715    637.95516131
   339.32269715    637.95516131
   353.63870639    644.44922417
   337.81935320    641.98560292
   337.81935320    641.98560292
0.23047     0.29688        0.75 
0.23047     0.29688        0.75 
0.91493     0.82918     0.78143 
0.91948     0.82593     0.77364 
]
>>
shfill
```

ShadingType 6 seems to be overkill for what I am trying to accomplish, but subdividing the quadrilaterals into triangles and doing linear interpolation produces something of lower quality.

Is there a more efficient way to code this effect such that the hundreds of quadrilaterals are rendered faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to speed this up significantly by replacing `shfill` with

```
gsave
x y w h rectclip
shfill
grestore
```

where `x` and `y` are the lower left coordinates of the encompassing rectangle, and `w` and `h` are the width and height of the rectangle.